# How do I install tkinter on Ubuntu for two separate versions of Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have two versions of Python 3 installed on Ubuntu 14.04, 3.4 and 3.5, I'd like to install tkinter for both.

When I use 
    `apt-get install python3-tk`, tkinter is only installed for Python 3.4 and an error is raised in 3.5 when I attempt to import the module.

Can I force `python3-tk` to install to Python 3.5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use Linux Mint (based on Ubuntu) and I use unofficial Python repositorium for Ubuntu.

https://launchpad.net/~fkrull/+archive/ubuntu/deadsnakes

It gives me `python3.5-tk`

```
apt-get install python3.5-tk
```

See how to add this repo: https://askubuntu.com/a/682875/177036

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [Miniconda](http://conda.pydata.org/miniconda.html). You can create different "environments" and run different versions of Python on the same machine and/or different packages on different python version. 
Like `conda create -n python3_5 python=3.5` then `source activate python3_5` and finally `conda install -y -n python3_5 python3-tk`.